# Rdirected site folder doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess

My web host directs traffic to the main *public_html* folder on the site for my main site. However, I want my main site to redirect to a subfolder for organizational reasons, so I can easily manage just the main site files within that folder. Therefore I want to redirect to *public_html\mysite.com*.

I created a .htaccess file in the *public_html* folder that does redirect properly when I just point it to a test index.html file.  However, when I try to point to index.php file used from Drupal, I get the following error.

> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@mysite.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

This is the content of the .htaccess file which lives in the *public_html* directory.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?<mysite>.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/<mysite>.com/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /<mysite>.com/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?<mysite>.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ <mysite>.com/production/dev-code/index.php [L]
```

Do I need to modify the .htaccess in public_html\mysite.com?  I don't have access to the server error log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a rewriteBase to your .htaccess file

```
RewriteBase /subdirectory
```

Note that this goes into the .htaccess file in the “subdirectory”, not your website root .htaccess file!

Answer (score 0):

I ultimately did not have to use RewriteBase. I changed the .htaccess in `public_html` and change the `$base_url` in my settings.php

My setup was such that I needed to redirect to a subdirectory(yourdomain.com) within a subdirectory(subdirectory) from the main `public_html` folder.  This is because for organizational purposes, I wanted everything to live under subdirectories. So the drupal installation was at `public_html\mydomain.com\subdirectory`

I modified the .htaccess at the `public_html` level to redirect to the subdirectory where drupal was installed.

yourdomain.com=the directory where you want your site to redirect to instead of the main `public_html`folder.

subdirectory = If you have an additional subdirectory structure to where your drupal installation goes.  I did this so that the drupal install would not live directly under the yourdomain.com because I wanted to keep my private directory there.

```
RewriteRule ^$ yourdomain.com/subdirectory/index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/yourdomain.com/subdirectory%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule .* yourdomain.com/subdirectory/$0 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* yourdomain.com/subdirectory/index.php?q=$0 [QSA]
```

The `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/yourdomain.com/subdirectory%{REQUEST_URI} -f` and corresponding rule were necessary because otherwise when you start clicking on links in your site, it will show http://yourdomain.com/subdirectory

Finally, you need to change the `$base_url` in settings.php to `http://yourdomain.com`